# For the line $w^Tx = 0$, how do we know the direction of the vector $w$

Tags: classification, classifier

On page [17/28 of Lecture 3: Linear Classification](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bonner/courses/2019f/csc411/lectures/03_classification_handout.pdf), why the slope of $w$ must be positive?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in the slides that suggests the line defined by w must have a positive slope. It happens to be in this picture, but w could be any vector.